# Install msql in Mac Osx

Tags: mysql, node.js, macos, sails.js

so I'm trying to use mysql as my database in sails js instead of mongodb, and I'm currently having a hard time configuring / installing it.

So basically what I did was in my app folder I typed

> npm install sails-mysql

then I fixed all my configuration for sails js and I'm having a 500(E_UNKNOWN) error when I open my application or I open a page that connects to mysql. It seems that I have not mysql running and installed. So following this, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-macosx-excerpt/5.5/en/macosx-installation-pkg.html I installed mysql. Now, I can't seem to locate mysql on my computer to start it. I know that it should be in /usr/local/bin but when I open it using the terminal

> open -a Finder /usr/local/bin

the mysql installation directory is not there. Is there anything that I'm missing? Or should I just install MAMP?

Comment: nvm, I used mdfind mysql in my terminal, I found out that mysql is installed in /usr/local/mysql :)